# How to create component in folder that is not in /src/app with Angular-Cli

Tags: angular-cli

I want to be able to create components or modules or services in folder external to /src/app/...

so i've tried with  ng g c ../mco/lib but it fail.

I want to be able to create with the CLI a component in folder external to app.

how can i achieve this ?

### EDIT

You can change the appRoot of AngularCli, so in angular-cli.json  i've added in "apps" array, a property  "appRoot": "mco"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the appRoot of AngularCli.

So in angular-cli.json

```
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "tr",
      "appRoot": "mco"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who finds `appRoot` is not working on `@angular/cli` 6. Here is a workaround:

```
{
"projects": {
"my-project": {
  "root": "/path/to/project",
  "projectType": "application",
  "schematics": {
      "@schematics/angular:component": {
        "path": "/path/to/project"
      },
      "@schematics/angular:directive": {
        "path": "/path/to/project"
      },
      "@schematics/angular:module": {
        "path": "/path/to/project"
      },
      "@schematics/angular:service":{
        "path": "/path/to/project"
      },
      "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
        "path": "/path/to/project"
      },
      "@schematics/angular:class": {
        "path": "/path/to/project"
      }
  }
}
}
```

Now you can run

```
ng g component hello-world --project=my-project --dry-run
```

to check if the `hello-world` is output to `/path/to/project/hello-world`.

Answer (score 3):

You can just define the right path and the angular-cli will get everything ready for you, for example if you want the component to be build outside app folder on a `example` folder you can try `ng g c ../example/yourComponent`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does not require modifying angular-cli.json

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this feature exists in `Angular CLI`. Assuming you are in `src/app` directory you can just create component in default location and then move it to desired place like this:

```
ng g c my-component; mv my-component /Users/username/desiredlocation/
```

Comment: i found the way to do it ;) i will edit my post to show how i did it

Comment: Nice :) You can also write answer to your own question.

Comment: Clearly, this is not what the op wants. Also, this prevents IDEs like VSCode to do refactoring changes