# Is there a way to rename the app folder to something more specific when using the angular cli

Tags: angular

I am currently using angular 6 with angular cli 6.2.6.
When we create a new project using the angular/cli , the folder structure that is generated is on type src/app , and all generate commands basically use this path to create modules/components etc.
Is there a way to change the path say from src/app => src/project-name

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

With latest version of CLI, In your angular.json file, you have an option projects called root that is used for specifying the directory of your apps root folder, relative to your configuration file.

You could for example put, a path like this, which might fit your need:

```
"projects": {
    "university-website": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
```

Comment: this still created an app folder in the path specified, however this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180496/how-to-create-component-in-folder-that-is-not-in-src-app-with-angular-cli